# VBA count emails module!

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

This is a follow-up question of one which I posted yesterday. I feel I am getting quite close to creating a module in VBA that will count the number of e-mails sent on a particular day of the week. For the moment the day chosen is Monday.

However, the code is not yet working, and Outlook refuses to see the particular module.
I am sure there are a couple of errors in it. If someone could point these out, I would greatly appreciate it.
I also think that such code could be useful for others for future reference as the code for this kind of module does not seem to be readily available on the internet (I've looked!) and yet forms a type of search parameter that many will find useful!

```
Sub Count2(Optional dteDate As Date)
  Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As Object
  Dim EmailCount As Integer    
  Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  On Error Resume Next

  Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("My Personal Emails").Folders("spam")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "No such folder."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Select Case Weekday(dteDate)
    Case vbMonday
      dteDate = Date
    End Select

  For Each MapiItem In MapiFolderInbox.Messages
    If MapiItem.TimeReceived = Date Then
      Count = Count + 1
      Next MapiItem   
    End If

  EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
  Set objFolder = Nothing
  Set objnSpace = Nothing
  Set objOutlook = Nothing

  MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " _
    & EmailCount, , "Number of spam messages sent on a Monday: " & Count        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst debugging drop the `on error resume next`.
It hides the errors. You can put it back later if you have to.
It's not a great idea to ignore errors, better to handle the errors explicitly.

One thing that struck me:

```
For Each MapiItem In MapiFolderInbox.Messages
    If MapiItem.TimeReceived = Date Then
      Count = Count + 1
      Next MapiItem   
    End If
```

Should be

```
For Each MapiItem In MapiFolderInbox.Messages
  If MapiItem.TimeReceived = Date Then
    Count = Count + 1
  End If
Next MapiItem
```

Other than that it looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

i think time received is more of a timestamp where in addition to date it would have time too. you should probably use it like this;

```
For Each MapiItem In MapiFolderInbox.Messages   
    If  MapiItem.TimeReceived > YTS And MapiItem.TimeReceived < TTS Then
        Count = Count + 1   
    End If 
Next MapiItem
```

where YTS and TTS are timestamps where it would have yesterday's timestamp and today timestamp

for eg 01:06:2011:23:59:00 and 02:06:2011:23:59:00

you should comfirm this by debuging your code. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook only sees the module when the parameters are left empty... as opposed to containing (Optional dteDate As Date).

Other than that, following the suggestion by Johan, the Module runs, but only ever has Count = 1. That is, that the result of emails received on a Monday is always 1 regardless of the input.

I also tried adbanginwar's suggestion, but in this case a compile error of 'Expected: Then or GoTo' is displayed.